# Javascript to generate a time string in an online form

Tags: javascript, string, time

I have a html form like this :

```
<form action="https://www.123.com/cgi-bin/action" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Product Name">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Product Name_2010_12_21_15_03">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="29.99">
</form>
```

How to use javascript to replace the above "Product Name_2010_12_21_15_03" with dynamically generated time string ?

Comment: Time string - in what format?

Comment: 2010_12_21_15_03  [ Year_Month_Day_Hour_Minute ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got it :

```
    <form action="https://www.123.com/cgi-bin/action" method="post" name="My_Form">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Product_Name">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="Product_Name">
      <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="9.99">
      <script type="text/javascript">
      <!--
        function getCorrectedYear(year)
        {
          year=year-0;
          if (year<70) return (2000+year);
          if (year<1900) return (1900+year);
          return year;
        }
        var today=new Date();
        var minute=today.getMinutes();
        if(minute<10) minute='0'+minute;
        var hour=today.getHours();
        if(hour<10) hour='0'+hour;
        var day=today.getDate();
        if(day<10) day='0'+day;
        var month=today.getMonth()+1;
        if(month<10) month='0'+month;
        var year=getCorrectedYear(today.getYear());
        var dateString=year+'_'+month+'_'+day+'_'+hour+'_'+minute;
        document.My_Form.item_number.value=document.My_Form.item_name.value+'_'+dateString;
      //-->
      </script>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var currentTime = new Date()
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
var day = currentTime.getDate()
var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
document.write("Product Name+" + year + "_" + month + "_" + day)
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: ugh ... `document.write()` is generally, and vehemently, deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the value of the input:

```
<input id='product_date_time' type='hidden' name='item_number' value=''>
<script>
  document.getElementById('product_date_time').value = new Date().toString();
</script>
```

The script does not have to immediately follow the input field, of course. It simply has to run at some point after the input element has been added to the DOM.

If you need more control over the format, you might want to look into the venerable [Date.js](http://datejs.com) library.

Comment: How to format it to this format : 2010_12_21_15_03 [ Year_Month_Day_Hour_Minute ] ?

Comment: Did you look at the Date.js library?  It's got a "toString" implementation (or something like that) to which you pass a format template, and it formats the Date instance.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment for the format "2010_12_21_15_03":

```
<input id='product_date_time' type='hidden' name='item_number' value=''>

<script>
function myDate () {
    var d = new Date();
    return d.getFullYear() + "_" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "_" + d.getDate() + "_" + d.getHours() + "_" + d.getMinutes();
}

document.getElementById('product_date_time').value = myDate();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need an alert window, I need to plug the value into the html form when I hit the submit button, how ?

Comment: The alert was an example to show it works. If you want it to be in the HTML form, follow Pointy's example above by assigning an "id" and then using getElementById() to set its value to myDate(). Are you using PHP or some other preprocessor? It might be easier to have the server-side set it dynamically.

Comment: Edited to include part of Pointy's for clarity to the author.